# Perl execute sql, print output to a file AND write to screen

Tags: perl, sqlplus

I call a SQL file thru my perl script, which writes the output to a log file, as:

```
system("sqlplus -s schema/pwd\@dbname \@$sql_file > $log_file");
```

However, I would like to have the output written to the screen as well. Is there a way to do this (other than re-executing the command sans writing to the log file)?

Comment: Would `tee` work in this case? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29

Comment: I would suggest rather than using `system` you may want to consider using the `DBI` module.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the results yourself and send them to both targets.

```
my $output = `sqlplus -s schema/pwd\@dbname \@$sql_file`;
print $output;
open( my $file, '>', $log_file ) or die $!;
print {$file} $output;
close $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively `tee` the output of the command, and save some memory, by reading its `STDOUT` using a pipe:

```
open(my $cmdfh, "sqlplus -s schema/pwd\@dbname \@$sql_file |") or die $!;
open(my $logfh, '>', $log_file ) or die $!;

while (<$cmdfh>) { 
    print; 
    print {$logfh} $_;
}

close $logfh;
close $cmdfh;
```